# Files automatically deleted

Tags: data-recovery, user-data

Hi all i am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Everything was right yesterday night. When i open my laptop today morning all my desktop files are deleted automatically. I searched in trash and peek into hidden files but no use. So much of important data is there in it. Can anybody help me to get my data back. Please...

Comment: Sounds like if you were using the Guest account?

Comment: No i am the admin

Comment: when you solve this problem, keep in mind to store your data in local folders, not on the desktop -> why would you do that ? and always keep backups. I think the answer below will help you restore what you've lost, if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

BEFORE DOING ANYTHING :
I strongly recommend you to use a live usb to try and recover your data. Do not boot Ubuntu from your hard drive, or you are at risk to permanently overwrite your lost data on your hard drive.

See the tool photorec.

To install it :

```
$ sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

This will install testdisk and its subcomponent photorec. testdisk is more powerful but can make you loose data, so use photorec first. photorec only reads data, so it's safe to use (By the way, you can use photorec as a user when you must be root to use testdisk).

```
$ photorec
$ sudo testdisk # Use that one as a second choice.
```

It's a console software, I hope you won't be afraid :-D.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step